# How to stop a loop that creates promises when any one of them fails?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to download some files that come split into multiple parts, each file has a N number of parts between 1 and 9999. I need to wait for every file to download to then process them together.

```
  const partsPromises = [];
  let finished = false;

  for (let i = 1; i < 10000 || finished; i++) {
    const part = String(i).padStart(5, '0'); // Part numbers are formated with 5 digits

    const prom = downloadPart(id, part); // Consider I'm given this id before this code by the user
    prom.catch(() => finished = true);
    /* This doesn't work as intended, I would like 
      for the first promise to fail to inmediately stop the loop */
    
    partsPromises.push(prom);
  }

  Promise.allSettled(videoPartsPromises).then(() => {
    // After all promises have settled I process the files
  });

function downloadPart(videoId, partNum) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log(`Downloading part ${partNum}`);
    https.get(
      `PART URL`,
      (response) => {
        if (response.statusCode === 403) {
          reject();
          return;
        }

        const file = fs.createWriteStream(`${partNum}.file`);

        response.pipe(file);
        resolve();
      }
    );
  });
}
```

Any ideas on how could I achieve this behaviour?

Comment: I might start by simplifying your example to something a little more generic. The donwload stuff really doesn't get to the core of what you are asking.  Also I might look at the implementation of ```race``` and ```any``` to give you some insight how you might solve this problem.  But I would certainly simplify it before rtrying to write that code. For example ```const getPromise = function() { return (generateRandBoolean()) ? Promise.resolve("okay") : Promise.reject("error"); }``` might be a suitable replacement for the download stuff. so long as ``getRandBoolean``` works in a reasonable way

Comment: also i thinkg the *fluture* supports that type of thing.  but that is monadic futures as opposed to promises.